# Report item width of items in TreeView via NM_CUSTOMDRAW?

Tags: winapi, treeview, comctl32

Is there a `WM_MEASUREITEM` type item for custom drawing treeview items via `NM_CUSTOMDRAW`?  I'd like to be able to report the width the item will actually be once I paint it in the post paint so a horizontal scrollbar doesn't show up when not needed (because I truncate the text with a ...).

Thanks.

Comment: You can prevent horizontal scrollbars from appearing by setting the `TVS_NOHSCROLL` style.

Comment: There is `TVM_GETITEMRECT` but I'm not sure whether it gives you the required width or just the clipped width. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/commctrl/nf-commctrl-treeview_getitemrect

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, there is no equivalent of `WM_MEASUREITEM` for a TreeView control.